# How can I hide the Find My Location buttons?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

In ArcGis 3.x, is there a way to hide the `Find my location` buttons in the search boxes? No matter how much I try, I can't find that bullseye control in dev tools of the browser. Thanks.

**Update:** These two fields are using the `Directions` widgets.

[image]

Comment: Which widget are you using? (the one with find my location button)

Comment: Thanks, @cabesuon. Checking on that and will get back

Comment: It's an `esri/dijit/Search` widget

Comment: Hi Alex .. Is it a custom widget? .. Can you add some code to the post?

Comment: Thanks, @cabesuon. Sorry for the delay in answering. No, it's actually the `Directions` widget, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the style in order to hide the button, something like this should work,

```
.LocateButton {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @cabesuon. That worked! I tried finding that element using Chrome's dev tools and I just couldn't see it. You're a genius with this easy solution!

Comment: @Alex glad it helps you! .. The tricky part was that the element is added when hover over the input then remove, that was maybe why you could not find it.

Comment: That explains why I couldn’t find it in the DOM :)